# Getting Cannot parse the request. (ErrorCode: InvalidRequestFormat) on Module Update-AzureRmVmss on PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, subnet, nic

I am trying to add a second subnet to a Azure Virtual Machine Scale Set using PowerShell.

The code I'm using is:

```
Add-AzureRmAccount

Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"


$vnetname = "confvnet"

$loc = "West Europe"

$backendSubnetName = "conf-jira-interlink"

$backendSubnetConfig = New-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $backendSubnetName -AddressPrefix "10.1.0.0/24"

echo "backendSubnetConfig: "$backendSubnetConfig

$vnet = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -Name $vnetname -ResourceGroupName "resourcegroup-confluence-jira-datacenter"

echo "vnet: "$vnet

Add-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $backendSubnetName -VirtualNetwork $vnet -AddressPrefix "10.1.0.0/24"

$subnetId = (Get-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $backendSubnetName -VirtualNetwork $vnet).Id

echo "subnetId: "$subnetId

$ipCfg = New-AzureRmVmssIPConfig -Name 'eth1' -SubnetId $subnetId 

echo "ipCfg: "$ipCfg

$backendSubnet = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $backendSubnetName -VirtualNetwork $vnet

echo "backendSubnet: "$backendSubnet

$vmss = Get-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName resourcegroup-confluence-jira-datacenter -VMScaleSetName confcluster

echo "vmss: "$vmss

Add-AzureRmVmssNetworkInterfaceConfiguration -Name $backendSubnet -Primary $false -IPConfiguration $ipCfg -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss


Update-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName "resourcegroup-confluence-jira-datacenter" -VMScaleSetName "confcluster" -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss
```

But I am getting the error message

```
Update-AzureRmVmss : Cannot parse the request.
ErrorCode: InvalidRequestFormat
ErrorMessage: Cannot parse the request.
ErrorTarget:
StatusCode: 400
ReasonPhrase: Bad Request
OperationID : 94e52a04-67c4-4390-bbea-74849ccce4ac
In X:\JIRA_Confluence_Migration\PowerShell\network-interfaces-azure-same-vnet.ps1:45 Zeichen:1
+ Update-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName "resourcegroup-confluence-jira- ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Update-AzureRmVmss], ComputeCloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.Automation.UpdateAzureRmVmss
```

on the command `Update-AzureRmVmss`.

Can anyone help me how I am using the `Update-AzureRmVmss` command wrong?

Comment: Any update for the question? Does the solution work for you?

Comment: Hi sorry, for the late answer. Don't need the solution anymore since the customer doesn't need the solution anymore.

Answer (score 2):

To add a second subnet to an Azure Virtual Machine Scale Set, most steps you have done are right and you know the subnet should in the same virtual network as the VMSS already in. Just some parameters you can change like below.

```
Add-AzureRmVmssNetworkInterfaceConfiguration -Name a_string_name -Primary $false -IPConfiguration $ipCfg -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss
```

The parameter `-Name` should have a string value. See it [Add-AzureRmVmssNetworkInterfaceConfiguration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.compute/add-azurermvmssnetworkinterfaceconfiguration?view=azurermps-6.13.0).

And there is also a step you need to do. It's that you need to deallocate the VMSS and then update the VMSS. It cannot support update the VMSS in the running state.